# How to df.loc a cell in a Pandas dataframe with repeating index values?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, indexing

So I have a big pandas dataframe (excel) that looks something like this:

```
Teams       Season      Points
Team A        1           5
Team B        1           6
Team C        1           4
Team D        1           5
Team A        2           7
Team B        2           8
Team C        2           3
Team D        2           2
```

You can see that all teams repeat in the index. My question is- is there a way I can "loc" onto a specific cell in this sheet

if i were to do df.loc["Team A", "Points"] it prints both Team A values.  Is there a way I can specify WHICH Team A I want to use (season 1 or 2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions with [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
print (df.query('Teams=="Team A" and Season==1')['Points'])
Teams
Team A    5
Name: Points, dtype: int64
```

---

```
print (df.query('Teams=="Team A" & Season==1')['Points'])
Teams
Team A    5
Name: Points, dtype: int64
```

If need scalar output:

```
#unutbu solution from deleted answer
print (df.query('Teams=="Team A" & Season==1')['Points'].item())
5

print (df.query('Teams=="Team A" & Season==1')['Points'][0])
5
print (df.query('Teams=="Team A" & Season==1')['Points'].values[0])
5
```

Another possible solution is created `MultiIndex` - add column `Season` to `index` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then select:

```
df = df.set_index('Season', append=True)
print (df)
               Points
Teams  Season        
Team A 1            5
Team B 1            6
Team C 1            4
Team D 1            5
Team A 2            7
Team B 2            8
Team C 2            3
Team D 2            2

print (df.loc[('Team A',1)])
Points    5
Name: (Team A, 1), dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, the MultiIndex is what I need I believe.  But, what if I have more columns other than Points, and I want to specify which column to pull from ?  Example I tried:

`print (df.loc([(player_or_team_name, rand_season)], [stat_name]))`

I get TypeError: __call__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I think I might just have the format, parenthesis / brackets out of place?

Comment: also df.query gives me an empty series with no value ? :  `Series([], Name: Caps, dtype: object)`

Comment: You can check docs - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers for selecting multiindex.